# gcc auto dependency full path

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, g++

I have a simple project - it has a `foo.cxx` and a `bar.h`:

```
// bar.h
// nothing

// foo.cxx
#include "bar.h"
// nothing else
```

If I include `bar.h` with `""`s, then the dependency file has everything with its full paths:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -MP -MMD -MF /home/barry/sandbox/foo.d 
      -c /home/barry/sandbox/foo.cxx -o /home/barry/sandbox/foo.o

$ cat foo.d
/home/barry/sandbox/foo.o: /home/barry/sandbox/foo.cxx \
 /home/barry/sandbox/bar.h

/home/barry/sandbox/bar.h:
```

However, if I include it with `<>`s and add `-I.`, I just get `bar.h` by itself:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -I. -MP -MMD -MF /home/barry/sandbox/foo.d 
      -c /home/barry/sandbox/foo.cxx -o /home/barry/sandbox/foo.o

$ cat foo.d
/home/barry/sandbox/foo.o: /home/barry/sandbox/foo.cxx bar.h

bar.h:
```

Is there a way to get the full paths for *all* of the files?

Comment: Why do you want full paths for `<>` includes? `gcc` will search the standard and `-I` paths for them when it needs them. It will not do that for `""` includes.

Comment: @EtanReisner We have a lot of code that uses `<>`s for local library includes too, and I'd like to try to avoid having to replace all of them.

Comment: That's what the `-I` flag is for.

Comment: @EtanReisner Yeah so I guess the solution is lots of replacing? Nothing I can do with gcc to get it to do what I want?

Comment: If you want gcc to output the correct paths so the rebuild tracking works correctly then I think you need to fix your source to use the correct kind of include directives. You could try to post-process the `.d` files for "known" filenames if you really wanted but I'm not sure that's a good idea (or necessarily doable in a robust fashion).

Comment: @EtanReisner I found a way around it - thanks for all the help though. You're definitely right in that post-processing filenames sounds awful (or, not robust, if you want to be more polite)

Comment: @EtanReisner one trick I've done instead of post-processing `.d` files is to use `-MT` to specify a "filename" with an `=` in it so it forms a variable assignment instead of a dependency.

Comment: @o11c How does that work? Wouldn't that end up with an oddly named dependency with a colon in it? (Or a parse error from make?)

Comment: @EtanReisner it outputs something like `FOO = : a.c a.h b.h c.h`, where I call `gcc -MT 'FOO ='`. Then I can read `${FOO}` in the makefile and do logic to it, GNU make can do a *lot* with its functions, including dynamically compute variable names (useful when doing this with multiple files).

Comment: @o11c Ah, true. Yeah, I can see how that might be useful in certain circumstances. I'll have to file that sort of thing away in case I need it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with `-I.` When gcc is determining the include for `<bar.h>`, it will find it as `./bar.h`, and so it will get printed in the dependency file in that same way.

If I were to provide the full path via `-I` as well:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -I/home/barry/sandbox -MP -MMD 
      -MF /home/barry/sandbox/foo.d 
      -c /home/barry/sandbox/foo.cxx 
      -o /home/barry/sandbox/foo.o
```

Then regardless of `""` or `<>`, I get the full path of `bar.h` in `foo.d`, as desired.

Comment: That's interesting (and somewhat reasonable). Do you need the full path on the `-MF`, `-c`, and `-o` options for this to work? I would hope not.

Comment: @EtanReisner Full path on `-MF` only affects where the dependency gets written to. Full paths on the other two affect the `foo.o` and `foo.cxx` outputs in `foo.d`, yes.

Comment: Ah, you need those for the `file.o: file.cxx` bit of the `.d` file? I see.

Comment: @EtanReisner Correct.